# Java inheritance and access modifiers

Tags: java, inheritance, protected, access-modifiers

i am trying to create a class system like this:

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] m;
    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        //constructor
    }
    public int get(int row, int col) {
        return m[row][col];
    }
}

public class Vector extends Matrix {
    public Vector() {
        //constructor
    }
    public int get(int index) {
        return super.get(0, index);
    }
}
```

I want the Matrix.get(row, col) function to be public, but i don't want it to be public through the Vector class. I don't want this to be possible:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
int x = v.get(1, 1);
```

The private access modifiers doesn't help me, because it doesn't make the method available outside of the Matrix class (except for its inheritors)

Any ideas on how it could be done?

Comment: In that case, `Vector` shouldn't extend `Matrix`. Why do you want to achieve something like this? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: how about protected ;). try it and see

Comment: Its not possible. But you can do one thing you can override the get method in `Vector` class and deprecate it.                           `@Override
    @Deprecated
    /**
     * do not use method
     */
    public int get(int row, int col) {
       return -1;
    }`

Comment: @Sagiv can you tell us what is the reason behind that you don't want `Vector`'s object not to see the parent's `get` method? I mean what is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can try change the package structure and use default access modifier.

Comment: Do not inherit these classes. Have a superclass and extend that superclass with these two. The superclass could have the common functionality (transpose for example).

Comment: You could use composition instead of inheritance so `Vector` is basically a wrapper for a private `Matrix`.

Comment: @AndrewS that's what I am thinking on doing, but the drawback with this solution is that if I write a Matrix.mul(Matrix a, Matrix b) method it won't accept a multiplication of two vectors, although vectors are one dimensional matrices.

Comment: @javaguy I am writing a small math library. I don't want the Matrix.get method available through Vector because it doesn't make sense to request a value from the second+ column of a vector, because a vector is a one dimensional matrix. I don't want when I am using a vector to have two get methods to choose from.

Comment: `Matrix.mul(Matrix a, Matrix b)` doesn't look right to me since that suggests it's going to be a static method.  Given a `Matrix p` and a `Matrix q`, it seems the method signature should be `Matrix mul(Matrix a)`.  Example: `Matrix r = p.mult(q)`.  This could be overloaded to have `Matrix mul(Vector v)`.

Comment: The normal way of doing this if it is actually required is adding this to your vector class  `public int get(int row, int col) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible because if a class inherits another, you must be able to call all of the methods of the class you are inheriting.

If you don't want to be able to do this because the index will be out of bounds, then add a `getRows()` and `getColumns()` method to matrix and anyone who has an instance of a Vector will check to make sure when they call `get(int row, int col)` it won't throw an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class Vector extends Matrix {
  public Vector(int cols) {
    super(0, cols);
  }

  public int get(int index) {
    return get(0, index);
  }

  @Override
  public int get(int row, int col) {
    if (row > 0) {throw new IllegalArgumentException("row != 0");
    return super.get(0, index);
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could think to use composition over inheritance
The Vector class will become:

```
  public class Vector {
    private Matrix matrix;
    public Vector() {
      matrix = new Matrix();
    }
    public int get(int index) {
      return matrix.get(0, index);
    }
  }
```

Another solution could be to invert the inheritance:

```
 public class Matrix  extends Vector{
    private int[][] m;
    public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
      super(0);
    }
    public int get(int row, int col) {
      return m[row][col];
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
      return m[0][index];
    }
  }

  public class Vector {
    private int[] v;

    public Vector(int length) {
      v = new int[length];
    }
    public int get(int index) {
      return v[index];
    }
  }
```